# How to go to parent activity from sub children activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, parent

Imaginarily, I have a parent activity called 'P'. Mr P has 5 children, called '1','2','3','4','5'.

But the truth in my project is ,

- P have 1 as child.
- 1 have 2 as child.
- 2 have 3 as child.
- and so on.

I travel from P to 1, and from 1 to 2, from 2 to 3, and so on.

**The problem is how can i travel from 3 straight to P ?** therefore P must be his parent am i wrong?

Here is what i have implemented so far on my back pressed

```
@Override 
    public void onBackPressed(){
      if (background_tick != null){
          if(background_tick.isPlaying())
              background_tick.stop();
          background_tick.release();
         // finish();
      }
      Intent crush=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),P.class);
      startActivity(crush);
      //super.onBackPressed();
 }
```

With that code i successfully go to activity P, but when i press 'Back' from P it return to acitivy 3 and i dont want that happen.

Any answer will appreciated guys.
greetings from bali.

Comment: Good Afternoon gentlemen. - depends where in the world we are.  Maybe we are ladies.

Comment: simply call `finish()` after `startActivity(crush)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Controll Android back stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142936/how-to-controll-android-back-stack)

Comment: Mr SMR : it didn't worked. The same problem happen.

Userblabla : Sorry, then for you good evening ladies.

Comment: Just so you understand why your code didn't work.  Activities are not strictly parent or child.  Its more like building a cake, u used a P layer, then a C layer, then a P layer again.  So when you remove the last P, you are back to C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your Intent Flag . it remove activity from top.

```
Intent crush=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),P.class);
crush.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(crush);
```

[Intent Flag](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks)

Comment: Maybe add a link to http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks to explain the different flags and their behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Uses the Flag

```
 Intent i = new Intent(3.this,P.class);
 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(i);
```