# Android Activity history tracking and clearing partially

Tags: android, android-activity, android-navigation

Imagine this activity history stack:

**A > B > C > D > E**

scenario 1:

If the user is on **E** then on tapping the back button it should navigate to **D > C > B > A**.

scenario 2:

If the user is on **E** then on tapping a custom button **"Show B"**, then it should clear **E > D > C**. Which is similar to **Finish()**.

Like X > Y  if we set **finish** on Y the X will be displayed. Similar If I tape **Show B** on **E** then **E > D > C** should be cleared from the stack.

I need to achieve both scenarios.

***(Edited ^^^^ with scenarios)***

If the user is on **E** activity and wants to move **B**. If **B** is in history stack can we **clear C > D > E** so that user can navigate to **B** without startActivity(B). and A should be in history.

If an activity is available in the stack then it should load from history if not startActivity(B).

If I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP/FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, it will clear full history and start's new activity.

I want to clear partial history.

Will it be possible to achieve? If so, how to do it please?

Comment: You can pass flags when starting activity *(I.e. `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` if that's your case)*.

Comment: Read the Android documentation on activity backstack and read this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142936/how-to-control-android-back-stack https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: Also, look at newer available methods and tools for app navigation. You can start including these into your project; https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0Cs2MQxyIs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GCXtCjtg40

Comment: @rajkavadia updated my question. Naseem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all pretty standard. Don't use any special launch modes. Normally, pressing BACK will just finish the current `Activity` and drop you back into the previous one.

For this case:

> If the user is on E then on tapping a custom button "Show B", then it
>   should clear E > D > C. Which is similar to Finish().

In `E`, to go back to the existing instance of `B`, do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will finish E, D and C and return to the existing instance of B.

The flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` tells Android to clear all activities between the current `Activity` and the target `Activity`. If you **don't specify** `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` then the existing instance of the target `Activity` will also be finished and a new instance will be created. If you **do specify** `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` then the existing instance of the target `Activity` **will NOT be** finished and a new instance **will NOT be created**.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

in your manifest file. For more refer this documentation https://android.jlelse.eu/android-activity-launch-mode-e0df1aa72242

Comment: Please don't suggest using the special launch modes `singleTask` or `singleInstance`. These create more problems than they solve, the side-effects are not well documented or undertstood, and they are not necessary in 99% of the situations. This is bad advice.